# Automatically building a 3d object using 2d layouts or images?

Tags: modeling, objects

Is there a way to automatically build a 3D object by using 2D layouts or images?

I have layouts for a house and it would be great if these layouts can be automatically transformed into a 3D object.

Comment: No such thing exists. Making 3D objects requires user intervention and understanding of the tools.

Comment: Theoretically you can convert layouts to to vectors (.svg), import to Blender and extrude. Practically is nonsense doing it this way.